# Get Error too many Sign Up Attempts. How i ask Selenium wait for 10 min, using Java

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver

On hosted eCommerce platform, I am trying to create 10000 Accounts. Using Selenium web-driver. But after creating 5 Customers get Error Too many Sign Up Attempts. Sign Up after 10 minutes. 
Is there any way so that i will create thousands of Accounts on my test Store.

Comment: Is this your own website?

Comment: Yes, One of our client moving there store from old to new hosted eCommerce platform, They want that customer are created from frontend. Set password and confirmation email sent to there old customers.  So that they create there accounts

Comment: I think for this task it is easy to move database rather than create entry. its fine , but this login/signup attempts restricted from server side I think or from code so if you have done any code for limited attempts then contact to server technical team.

Comment: i'd agree that recreating the entries via the web front end is a bit, ermm - primitive. I'd go with the normal route which is to examine all the core configs and just make the changes there tbh. oh and btw -the probable reason for the block after 5 signups will be due to the sensible adoption of a rate limit against a single ip address.

Comment: Why wouldn't you talk to your own dev team and have them help you create all those accounts?

Comment: Okay. Is there any other way by using proxies

Comment: @HelpingHands How i ask Selenium wait for 10 min, using Java

Comment: @mani - you can apply appropriate wait , Please check here  : http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/wait-commands/